# ArgumentError in UsersController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to print the all the users in the index page, I'm passing the `users` to the index page.

users_controller.rb

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

index.html.erb

```js
<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Additional errors,

```
app/helpers/users_helper.rb:4:in `gravatar_for'
app/views/users/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb__319283733763486353_69882358987600'
app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__319283733763486353_69882358987600'
```

Comment: Please add the code of `users_helper.rb` since `gravatar_for` is implemented in this file.

Answer (score 3):

Based on http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gravatar_for/0.1.2, try this code instead:

```
gravatar_for user.email
```

Assuming the email of the user can be accessed this way.

Comment: Is it the same gem? Is your user's email accessible through `user.email` ?

Comment: Issue was that I was passing two parameters to `gravatar_for` method, but it was defined to accept only one parameter, so I tried to run the file by removing the `size : 50` and it worked.

Comment: You should be able to pass additional argument such as `size`. Refer to this guide: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gravatar_for/0.1.2/GravatarFor/ViewHelpers, just make sure you're passing the email directly